# Installing ubuntu 20.04 server: how to delete a partition?

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04 server. While in the «Storage configuration» step, among the «available devices» I want to delete a partition.
That partition is labelled as such: `partition 7 existing, already formatted as ext4, not mounted`.

When I press the space bar on that partition, I get a window where I have to choose between `close`, `Edit`, `Delete *`.

When I choose delete I get the following message: `Cannot delete a single partition from  device that already has partitions`.

How to delete that partition? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and if I remember it correctly, the option to delete the partition is hidden under the option to format it.

This is not so intuitive, hopefully this will be corrected by the developers.

Comment: As I said, When I press the space bar on that partition, I get a window where I have to choose between `close`, `Edit`, `Delete *`. When I press the `Edit` option, I have a `Format` option from where I can choose the file system I want to format the partition with `ext4`, `xfs`, `btrfs`, `swap`. None of those options allow me to format.

Comment: Question edited to add screen pictures.